# Order elements in view or in view model?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, short

I am using the MVVM pattern and I would like to sort the elements on a datagrid. In my view model I have an ObservableCollection with the element for the datagrid.

In the datagrid I can sort element cliking in the column name, so that is nice, and for multiple columns. I like this feature.

However, I would like to do some more specific ordering, for example show first the element which the ColumnB has "valueC" and later the rest of the elements, and when I sort for a column name, order for that column but show first the elements with "valueC" and later the rest of the elements sorted by the column that I clicked.

To do that, I can sort the elements in the ObservableCollection of the view model, but I think that this functionality is more something that it would be done in view, plus because I would like to sort by columns, so I would have to say to the view the column that is clicked.

However, I don't know if it is posible to do this kind of complex sorts in the view, perhaps with some converter or with any way.

Thank so much.

Comment: If you did it in your View, your View would then have to make assumptions on the data that you have in your ViewModel, which may not be correct. Do it in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every logic has to be done in the ViewModel. View must not know anything about the logic behind displayed datas.

In a simple case you could order your items in a view but in a realistic case, ordering will not affect only visible items but it affects also items not shown because of the paging.

Comment: But how to order then by many columns in the datagrid if the ordering is done in the view model? How know the view model the columns that the use click in the view?